# Difference between Testng class and normal Java class

Tags: selenium

What is the difference between Testng Class and a normal Java class. While creating an Automation suite in Selenium should we use Testng class or normal java class in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

TestNg is not language it's a testing framework. See [this](http://testng.org/doc/index.html)

**TestNG is a testing framework inspired from JUnit and NUnit**

This is a framework to handle different kind of testing such as unit,end to end, functional and so more. It uses `Java` and provide supports and annotations to drive testings. That's it!

Answer (score 1):

A `TestNg` class is a `Java` class, but a `Java` class does not have to be a `TestNg` class.

The following is from the TestNg documentation and gives an understanding what you can do with the `TestNg` class:

> This class is the main entry point for running tests in the TestNG
>   framework. Users can create their own TestNG object and invoke it in
>   many different ways:
>
> ```
> On an existing testng.xml
> On a synthetic testng.xml, created entirely from Java
> By directly setting the test classes
> ```
>
> You can also define which groups to include or exclude, assign
>   parameters, etc...

From: http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/TestNG.html

TestNg is basically is a set of code written in `Java` that allows you to create tests.

Comment: I don't agree with **A TestNg class is a Java class, but a Java class does not have to be a TestNg class.** If `TestNG` is not a language how can that have a class?

Comment: @Saifur, there is nothing to disagree about. You can have many different `Java` classes that are not related to the TestNg class. But a TestNg class is a Java class.

Comment: @Paul, TestNG class is any class which have TestNG annotation. It can be Java class, Ruby class or anything based on your programming language

Answer (score 0):

A TestNG class is a Java class that contains a method annotated by this class:  `org.testng.annotations.Test;`

Answer (score 0):

**Testng Class and a normal Java class**

**TestNG Class:** TestNg class is nothing but any normal class with TestNG annotation and Annotation is a tag that represents the metadata which gives the addition information about class, methods and interface.

> To know more about annotation Please refer this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/

While creating Automation suite we use either JUNIT or TestNG. JUNIT or TestNG are testing framework. They have their own set of libraries and annotations which is useful to run our automation suite. JUNIT or TestNG makes easy to run automation suite or generate reports of build run. They provide the feature to setup or cleanup activity using Before and After annotation which is require in almost every autoamtion suite.

TestNG also provide us flexibility to execute our automation script based on our requirement like we can group of test cases, we can include or exclude methods, parallel execution of test methods and many more.

> Please refer this to know more about TestNG.
>   http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

**I hope this will help.**